# JSP compilation in servlet mapping during runtime

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

How does jsp compilation work for the below configuration. Even when run time compilation is disabled. Tomcat compiles the file '/jsp/myjsp.jsp' at runtime.

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>S1</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/jsp/myjsp.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>S1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myjsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Edit:

I removed jsp org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet configuration in $CATALINA\conf\web.xml So that runtime compilation does not work

Edit2:
Before closing the question, read the question properly. I have disabled runtime compilation. Still tomcat compiles the jsp at runtime when it is mentioned in servlet mapping, Question is how does this occur

Note: JSP placed  inside any folder is not compiled when accessed using absolute path

When run time compilation is removed, following cases occurs.

```
JSP 1: Accessed directly without servlet-mapping in web.xml
Ex: http://localhost:8080/jsp/notcomplied.jsp
```

It just prints the java code when url is loaded

```
JSP 2: JSP is configured in servlet-mapping mentioned above in question.
Ex: http://localhost:8080/msjsp
```

Java code is compiled and output is printed.

Expected output for JSP 2: Print the java code in the file.

Comment: @ScaryWombat JSP i have added is not a controller. it is just a view. 

My question is even when run time compilation is disabled, How class file is created inside 'tomcat/work' folder?

Comment: Tomcat compiles JSP files at runtime, it can't even execute a JSP without compiling it first. Can you clarify what do you mean by "compilation is disabled"?

Comment: @Sergei I removed 

<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>

configuration in $CATALINA\conf\web.xml

So that runtime compilation does not work